# Como relacionar uma pergunta com outra manualmente, sem fazer comentários?

Tags: suporte

Hoje vi na home essa pergunta de 2014

[Não usar chaves "{ }" em IF no PHP pode gerar problemas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25184/n%C3%A3o-usar-chaves-em-if-no-php-pode-gerar-problemas)

Lembrava vagamente de ter respondido algo muito similar e com certa dificuldade encontrei:

[Qual a diferença entre os usos do foreach no php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162974/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-usos-do-foreach-no-php)

O intuito era postar links de uma pergunta em outra para ficarem relacionadas e mais fáceis de consultar.

Mas então pensei em perguntar aqui se já não existe alguma ferramenta para fazer esse relacionamento.

Existe tal recurso? Talvez com uso das tags?

Ou podemos apenas adicionar em forma de comentário?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Sugestão

Seria interessante uma ferramenta para fazer essa relação manualmente pois tornaria mais simples. Aqui tive o "trabalho" de postar os links nas duas perguntas. Se existisse uma ferramenta poderia postar link numa só e apareceria automaticamente na ou nas outras marcadas como relacionadas.

## Observação

*Estou ciente que existe uma automação que mostra temas relacionados e fica no lado direito da tela. Acredito que deve ser ligado as tags:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas se entrar em quase qualquer pergunta irá notar várias postagens relacionadas, o sistema tenta identificar isto além das tags, provavelmente a mesma condição/algorítimo para procurar duplicatas. Os links somente fazem os relacionados linkados ficarem acima dos demais, isto porque o sistema prefere confiar na comunidade para organizar seu conteudo, o que faz todo sentido.

Comment: Vale lembrar que quando você linka uma pergunta com outra ela aparece na lateral direita como "Vinculado", quando o sistema sugere ela aparece como "Relacionado".

Comment: Humm blz, entendi. Então basta colocar o link no comentário.